# Replace into Sql (Not all line just special letter inside it)

Tags: sql, replace

I'm a beginner with SQL. I always use `update`, `set` and `where` commands to replace values with other values. For example:

`update _Items SET CodeName = 'ITEM_07_CH' where CodeName = 'ITEM_08_CH'`.

What if i want to replace just small letter into a column just like using notepad++ (ctrl + H)? e.g. find (`_08_`) and replace it with (`_07_`). How do I do this in SQL?

Please note that I have about 2000 values in the table and I can't do it one by one. I just wanna replace this letter in the whole column.

Comment: well, when you UPDATE a column, you will always overwrite the complete value of that column. I think your database design has a flaw... "ITEM_07_CH" does not look like a normalized value if you need to update 2000 rows from 08 to 07 in every one? but you can of course still use REGEX() and REPLACE() to do the work for you on every of the 2000 rows

Comment: most platforms have some sort of string `Replace(column, for, with)` function

Comment: cant you write a simple query ?

Comment: @user2010164 is that the way to talk to a person trying to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example in MySQL (and also in the most RDBMS) you can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function.

```
update _Items SET CodeName = REPLACE(CodeName,'_08_','_07_') 
where CodeName LIKE '%_08_%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
update _Items SET CodeName = REPLACE(CodeName,'_08_','_07_') where CodeName like 'ITEM_??_CH'
```